# VBA Excel: Filling in table with input from userform / jumps out sub

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a little problem with my vba code. I'm trying to fill in a table by using a userform.
They only have to fill in 3 values:
[userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aWji.png)

After the first time they clicked "Toevoegen" the line gets added properly into the table by this code:

```
Private Sub cbToevoegen_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim artikelnr As Long

'Validation
If IsDate(Me.tbDatum) = False Then
    MsgBox "Geef een geldige datum in vb.: 14-02-2022"
    Me.tbDatum.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If Me.cbArtikel.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox "Selecteer een Artikel uit de lijst"
    Me.cbArtikel.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNumeric(Me.tbAantal) = False Then
    MsgBox "Vul een geldig aantal in."
    Me.tbAantal.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

shBewegingen.Activate
With shBewegingen
    'Bepaal de laatste rij
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
    
    'Voeg inboeking toe
    .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = Me.tbDatum
    
    .Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = "IN"
    
    artikelnr = Val(Left(Me.cbArtikel, 5))
    .Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = artikelnr
    
    .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Val(Me.tbAantal)
    
    .Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = Environ("Username")
End With
shMagazijnbeheer.Activate

Me.cbArtikel.ListIndex = -1
Me.tbAantal = ""
End Sub
```

But the second time it just seems to fill in the first cell (with the date) and then jumps out of the sub...
What do I do wrong?

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfLV0.png)

Edit: It seems to go wrong when I choose for a second time the same artikel from the field cbArtikel...

Already thanks!

Comment: I guess it's because you set `Me.cbArtikel.ListIndex = -1` at the end of your sub, and the second time round, you check for when that equals `-1`, when it does, you have said for it to `Exit Sub`.

Comment: But it goes through that part and fills in a second time the first value (date) in the first cell and jumps out at the line: .Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = "IN"

Comment: Are you stepping through it (F8) to make sure it is there it jumps out? If so, after it jumps out of the sub, where does it end up - does it just finish, or is it in a parent procedure? If you skip over that line, does it continue? If there's a parent procedure, do you have error handling (e.g. `on error resume next`), if so, can you temporarily disable it to get the error?

Comment: Yes i'm stepping through it to see where it goes wrong, so i checked all my field values, they are all filled in (so not a -1 value for listindex) so it runs the line: .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = Me.tbDatum and then just ends, it doesn't give an error (I don't use the error resume next, so no error handling at the moment)

Comment: Does emptyRow have the correct row on the second run? Can you check its value in the immediate window each time? I wonder whether changing `emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1` to `emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A")) + 1` - notice the missing "."

Comment: Yes, but changed it with the missing dot anyway ;) and still doesn't want to add it after the date has been added on the new line :o probably missing something

Comment: Sorry, I'm stumped! Hopefully someone else can come to the rescue! One last thought would be to check the cells to make sure nothing is restricted, no formatting constraints etc.

Comment: @JoeJ no restraints or restrictions on the cells :) but still thanks for going through some checks with me :)

Comment: How is the combobox cbArtikel filled , is it by setting Rowsource ?

Comment: indeed with this code: `With shMasterdata
        lastrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A"))
        Set i = .Range("J2:J" & lastrow)
    End With
    Me.cbArtikel.RowSource = i.Address`